# Prisma error - Type mismatch when trying to create data

Tags: postgresql, prisma, next.js13

for a personal project that I am currently setting up the backend for I am trying to add a city to my database (Prisma using PostgreSQL), that city has 2 relations, one with User and one with Position. Now the way it should function is:

1. I navigate to someUrl/api/cities/[id] (id being the userId)
2. In the request is all the data for the city such as: cityName, country, date etc...
3. Then I want to add the city to the database in a way that it is connected to the user that added it but does not return the user data on the return and connected to the position of the city which is a one-to-one relation and it returns the position data from the query

Here is my full schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId            String
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.Text
  access_token      String? @db.Text
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.Text
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  username      String?   @unique
  password      String?
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  cities        City[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}

model City {
  id         String   @id @default(cuid())
  cityName   String
  country    String
  emoji      String
  date       String
  notes      String?
  position   Position @relation(fields: [positionId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  positionId String   @unique
  user       User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId     String

  @@unique([cityName, userId])
}

model Position {
  id   String @id @default(cuid())
  lat  Float
  lng  Float
  city City?
}
```

Here is the code for the function adding the city:

```
import prisma from "@/lib/db";
import { PrismaClientKnownRequestError } from "@prisma/client/runtime/library";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import * as z from "zod";

const citySchema = z.object({
  cityName: z
    .string()
    .min(1, "CityName is required")
    .max(100, "CityName is too long"),
  country: z
    .string()
    .min(1, "Country name is required")
    .max(100, "Country name is too long"),
  position: z.object({
    lat: z.number(),
    lng: z.number(),
  }),
  userId: z.string(),
  emoji: z.string().min(1, "Emoji is required").max(200, "Emoji is too long"),
  date: z.string().min(1, "Date is required").max(100, "Date is too long"),
  notes: z.string().min(1, "Notes is required").max(1500, "Notes are too long"),
});

export async function GET(
  req: Request,
  { params }: { params: { id: string } }
) {
  const cities = await prisma.city.findMany({
    where: {
      userId: params.id,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json({ cities }, { status: 200 });
}

export async function POST(
  req: Request,
  { params }: { params: { id: string } }
) {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    // const data = citySchema.parse(body);
    const { cityName, country, position, date, emoji, notes } =
      citySchema.parse(body);
    const userId: string = params.id;
    console.log(userId);

    const newCity = await prisma.city.create({
      data: {
        cityName,
        country,
        emoji,
        date,
        notes,
        userId,
        position: {
          create: {
            lat: position.lat,
            lng: position.lng,
          },
        },
      },
      include: {
        position: true,
      },
    });

    if (!cityName || !country || !position || !date || !emoji || !notes) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          message: "Some resource was not found",
        },
        { status: 404 }
      );
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          message: "City added successfully",
          newCity,
        },
        { status: 201 }
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
      if (error.code === "P2002") {
        return NextResponse.json(
          {
            message: `An instance of the values ${error.meta.target} already exists`,
          },
          { status: 409 }
        );
      }
    }

    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Some error has occurred", error },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fresh-nextjs-template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "migrate:dev": "npx dotenv -e .env.local -- prisma migrate dev",
    "db:push": "npx dotenv -e .env.local -- prisma db push",
    "migrate:reset": "npx dotenv -e .env.local -- prisma migrate reset",
    "db:seed": "npx dotenv -e .env.local -- prisma db seed",
    "prisma:generate": "npx dotenv -e .env.local -- prisma generate",
    "prisma:studio": "npx dotenv -e .env.local -- prisma studio",
    "production:build": "npx prisma generate && npx prisma migrate deploy && next build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.1",
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.3.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-alert-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.1.5",
    "@types/node": "20.6.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "eslint": "8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility": "^0.1.2",
    "leaflet-geosearch": "^3.9.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lucide-react": "^0.279.0",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "next-auth": "^4.23.2",
    "postcss": "8.4.29",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-day-picker": "^8.8.2",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.46.2",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "typescript": "5.2.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "zod": "^3.22.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.199",
    "@types/react-leaflet": "^3.0.0",
    "prisma": "^5.3.1"
  }
}
```

I tried changing the schema multiple times to no avail. I got absolutely no clue what the issue is and haven't found anything on the web related to it.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Type '{ cityName: string; country: string; emoji: string; date: string; notes: string; userId: string; position: { create: { lat: number; lng: number; }; }; }' is not assignable to type '(Without<CityCreateInput, CityUncheckedCreateInput> & CityUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & CityCreateInput)'.
  Type '{ cityName: string; country: string; emoji: string; date: string; notes: string; userId: string; position: { create: { lat: number; lng: number; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Without<CityUncheckedCreateInput, CityCreateInput> & CityCreateInput'.
    Type '{ cityName: string; country: string; emoji: string; date: string; notes: string; userId: string; position: { create: { lat: number; lng: number; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Without<CityUncheckedCreateInput, CityCreateInput>'.
      Types of property 'userId' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(5976, 5): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ select?: CitySelect<DefaultArgs>; include?: CityInclude<DefaultArgs>; data: (Without<CityCreateInput, CityUncheckedCreateInput> & CityUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & CityCreateInput); }'
(property) data: (Prisma.Without<Prisma.CityCreateInput, Prisma.CityUncheckedCreateInput> & Prisma.CityUncheckedCreateInput) | (Prisma.Without<Prisma.CityUncheckedCreateInput, Prisma.CityCreateInput> & Prisma.CityCreateInput)
The data needed to create a City.
```

it is coming from line 51 in the code provided above from the word 'data'

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the error by changing up the relation between City and Position like the following:

```
model City {
  id       String    @id @default(cuid())
  cityName String
  country  String
  emoji    String
  date     String
  notes    String?
  position Position?
  user     User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId   String

  @@unique([cityName, userId])
}

model Position {
  id     String @id @default(cuid())
  lat    Float
  lng    Float
  city   City   @relation(fields: [cityId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  cityId String @unique
}
```

I do not know why it fixed is as I am new to Prisma, if someone could explain it in the comments I would be grateful. Have a nice day!